# Hopefully Simple Error in Thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm a little new to Android. Working on an app that let's user input a number and then calculates the Fibonacci Sequence and then displays each element in the sequence at 1 second intervals. But I have an issue when I try to display using a thread inside a for loop. I try print from an array list but it gives me an error with my counter variable (j). I tried running this same exact method in a much simpler app and the array list worked just fine. I don't know why it doesn't work this time. I hope this is a simple obvious error. Can anyone tell me why? Code is posted below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// primary widgets
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Button button1;
Thread thread;
static ArrayList<Integer> fibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //Attempt to clear TextView
    textView.setText("");

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Clear Textview
            String array = " "; 
            fibList.clear();
            textView.setText(array);

            final String input = editText.getText().toString();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int tmp = 0;

            // confirm input
            if (number < 20) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You entered: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                    fibList.add(fib(i));

                    // sum even numbers
                    if (fib(i) % 2 == 0) {
                        tmp += fib(i);

                    }

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Number is too Large: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            Log.i("TEST", "ARRAY"+fibList);

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                  @Override
                  public void run(){

                    for(int j = 0; j < fibList.size(); j++){
                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                         @Override
                         public void run(){

                             //ERROR OCCURS HERE: Cannot refer to a non-final variable j 
                             //inside an inner class defined in a different method
                           textView.append(fibList.get(j).toString());

                           textView.append("");
                         }
                      });
                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } //wait one second
                    }
                  }

                });
                thread.start();
        }

    });
}

// run fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple workaround to solve your issue is to declare a temp `final` variable in this way:

```
       for(int j = 0; j < fibList.size(); j++){
             final int finalJ = j;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                   //ERROR OCCURS HERE: Cannot refer to a non-final variable j 
                   //inside an inner class defined in a different method
                   textView.append(fibList.get(finalJ).toString());
                   textView.append("");
                }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a more serious problem.
You are attempting to manipulate a texView from a thread.  That's not permitted.  Only the GUI thread can manipulate screen objects or else Bad Things Happen.

Take a look at AsyncTask.  It is designed to address exactly the problem you are trying to solve.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html